# WordPress stats API key

Tags: plugins, statistics, api

Everytime WordPress stats updates, I need to provide the API key. Is there some way to automate this?

Comment: This plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/

Comment: Yup..That's the one.

Comment: I've updated the plugin a few times on numerous blogs and never had to re-enter the API Key.

Do you have a similar issue with the Askimet plugin?

Comment: What other plug-ins are you running on that site?  There might be some interference by another system ... I've never had this problem on any site using WP Stats ...

Comment: @Adam, Now that I think of it, Akismet never gave me any problems. @EAMann Well, its a huge list, but I doubt that could be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/stats/tags/1.7.2/stats.php#L685

The deactivation hook deletes your database information. I'm guessing you're manually deactivating the plugin, updating, and then re-activating? If so, that runs the deactivation hook. Fortunately, that's not from the latest version. This is:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/stats/tags/1.7.3/stats.php#L686

So that shouldn't happen anymore.

By the way, you shouldn't think that this means you were doing anything wrong. They shouldn't be deleting information on deactivation, only on uninstall. Kind of strange that they were doing it at all...

Comment: Great! I always wondered why only the stats plugin was behaving weird.